# Dog barks for an hour when expecting owner home

Tags: dogs, vocalizations

My Friend rex the dog who lives with my neighbour barks his little stubby head off from 4-5:30 pm every day when he knows his owner is coming home.  During the day he lives in the yard, waiting.

How can balboa be taught not to bark and bark and bark and bark....

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I follow. Are you going to be _training_ the dog or is this a question about 'What can _you_, the next door neighbour, do to stop it the barking'?

Comment: the owner and i are going to try and train it.  but how? because there isn nobody there when he barks

Comment: Then I'd say these two are also related too: 
https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/114/how-to-prevent-my-dog-from-barking-constantly-when-i-am-not-at-home
https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10306/how-can-i-teach-my-puppy-to-not-bark-when-we-leave-the-room